# AJAX Upload > 50 MB ends with "oh-no!" message

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

Uploading a file to a rest service like this:

```html
<input type="file" style="display:none" id="eeeee" onchange="
   var f = files[0];
   var r = new FileReader();
   r.onload=function(e){
  var dat = new Int8Array(e.target.result);
  var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
  x.open('POST','rest/database/22/backup/');
  x.send(dat);
   };
   r.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
 "/>
 <button onclick="document.getElementById('eeeee').click();">Upload</button>
```

results in a:

[image]

Any idea how to avoid this problem?

### EDIT

I could reproduce the problem in the question. Press `Run code snippet` and upload a huge file (no sensitive files please, we never know who listen our network-traffic).

Comment: Check your webserver configuration, it may have a maximum upload limit.

Comment: PHP has an `upload_max_size` setting, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: @Barmar Webserver does not have a maximum upload limit. Non-ajax uploads > 200mb work. Also, if the server refuse the upload it should not be a `oh-no` message in the client but a server-side 5xx status-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a bug in chrome. Current version does work.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider uploading files in small chunks maybe using FileReader.onprogress

Comment: Its a chrome problem only. Id like to KISS (Keep it stupid simple). A form might be better but I dont know how to form-post without form-fields.